# PostgreSQL - How to use the result of previous record to insert a new record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a migration for my `customer` table where the my new column `new_number` should get incremental values (starting from 10000 because of a business rule) for each company like the following:

| id | company_id | new_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10000 |
| 2 | 1 | 10001 |
| 3 | 1 | 10002 |
| 4 | 2 | 10000 |
| 5 | 2 | 10001 |

I have written a query that does the trick by using a function that fetches the last inserted number and adds 1 to the new row. But is way too slow and causes timeout when run on thousands of rows.

```
create or replace function get_number (id_company uuid)
returns int
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
new_number integer;
begin
select
    c.new_number
into new_number
from
   customer c
where
  c.company_id = id_company
  and c.new_number is not null
order by c.new_number desc
limit 1;
return new_number;
end;
$$;

update
   customer c
set
    new_number =
        case
            when get_number(c.company_id) is null then 1 else get_number(c.company_id) + 1
            end
where c.new_number is null;
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly you can try to `ROW_NUMBER` window function instead of function.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM customer 
)
UPDATE customer t1
SET new_number = cte.rn + 9999
FROM cte
WHERE t1.new_number IS NULL AND t1.id = cte.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid a UDF and instead use an update join with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
UPDATE customer AS c1 
SET new_number = c2.rn
FROM
(
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM customer
) c2
WHERE c1.id = c2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is an ongoing need it would be better to create a trigger for insert.

> ```
> create table customer(id serial, company_id int, new_number int);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION customer_new_number_function()
>   RETURNS TRIGGER 
>   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
>   AS
> $$
> BEGIN
>   IF  NEW.new_number is null THEN
>        select coalesce(max(new_number),0) + 1  into NEW.new_number from customer where company_id = NEW.company_id;
>   END IF;
>
>   RETURN NEW;
> END;
> $$
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER customer_new_number_trigger
> BEFORE INSERT ON customer
> FOR EACH ROW 
> EXECUTE PROCEDURE customer_new_number_function();
> ```

> ```
> insert into customer (company_id) values (1),(1),(1),(2),(2);
> ```

> ```
> select * from customer;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | company_id | new_number
> -: | ---------: | ---------:
>  1 |          1 |          1
>  2 |          1 |          2
>  3 |          1 |          3
>  4 |          2 |          1
>  5 |          2 |          2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b8e18aa6d04fcd93fe56f218f97913af)*

Comment: I'd expect that this would lead to *duplicated* keys in case when two parallel inserts get the same `max`.

Answer (score 0):

If the new columns is used only for reporting purposes (i.e. is not as a search key) you may also define the *new_column* only as a view column.

**Example**

```
create view v_company as 
select 
 id, company_id,
 9999+row_number() over (partition by company_id  order by id) as new_number
from customer;

select * from v_company
order by id;

id|company_id|new_number|
--+----------+----------+
 1|         1|     10000|
 2|         1|     10001|
 3|         1|     10002|
 4|         2|     10000|
 5|         2|     10001|
```

The **big advantage** of this *lightweight* solution is that you will not have to solve the probems *after* the migration with the assignment of the new values.

You can't use *identity* or *serial* column due to your business logic.

The proposed "trigger" assignment solution in an other answer will lead to duplication if you insert concurrently two customers in the same company and the triggers get the identical current `max` value.

I'll have a hard time to keep the `new_column` unique and without gaps with some user defined serialization.